# Using variables as href in anchor tags (PHP)

Tags: php, the-events-calendar

I'm trying to create an anchor tag and using a variable as the link.

Here's what my template looks like.

```
<?php 
  $website = tribe_get_event_website_link();
  echo '<a href="' . $website. '">REGISTER</a>';
?>
```

So I'm creating a variable that will hold the link the I want to anchor it. And when I echo it back, it appears, but it doesn't come out properly. Here's what it looks like.

[image: html]

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong?

edit:

I also tried

```
<a href="<?php echo $website ?>">REGISTER</a>
```

but it still produces the same thing.

Comment: Looks like that `tribe_...` function is already echoing it.

Comment: alright cool. So if I  just use 'echo $website' it works fine and displays the link address. I want to make it an anchor with the text 'REGISTER'. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you saying that using `echo $website` displays, as just text, the url: `http://google.com` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a WordPress related question, but it's a simple one. The `tribe_get_event_website_link()` function you are using outputs a full link. You can use SimpleXML to extract the `href` part and then use it later. It's as simple as this:

```
$website = tribe_get_event_website_link();
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement( $website );
echo '<a href="' . $xml['href']. '">REGISTER</a>';
```

If you are unable to store the functions value inside a variable (for example, if the function echos it), you can use `ob_get_clean()`:

```
ob_start();

tribe_get_event_website_link();

$website = ob_get_clean();
```

Now proceed with extracting the `href` as mentioned above.

Comment: I think OP just has the wrong function for what he wants to do. But that _(and the fact that this whole question is off topic)_, aside, **thank you** for that SimpleXML example. I think it just solved something else for me. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `tribe_get_event_website_link()` with [`tribe_get_event_website_url()`](https://theeventscalendar.com/function/tribe_get_event_website_url/).

The first one is generating the link code. The second is just returning the url, which is what you need for the `href`.